# Android Shazam / Soundhound from custom database? Identify music from custom database

Tags: android, shazam

We know about shazam , soundhound and etc but all of them use own database, what if I have a self database with music and want to identify listening music from my own database? Does an some application for android exists, that provides identifing from my own database?

What suggestiongs to solve this problem as easy as possible?

maybe exists custom echoprint server (with music upload), and ready-to-use android app to work with them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can look at Echoprint: http://echoprint.me/
It's open-source under MIT License.
And there is an android application: https://github.com/gvsumasl/EchoprintForAndroid
Also open-source under MIT License

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make own server and app. I'm looking for service that provide this features, if this doesn't exists no other way - only create..

Comment: If server, maybe normal installations exists?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really know, because I haven't tried it before. The only I can give to you: http://echoprint.me/start#identify – This is what they say about identifying a song on your own server. There are links to codegen project (https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-codegen/blob/release-4.12/README.md) and echoprint server (https://github.com/echonest/echoprint-server) with installation guide in readme

Answer (score 1):

I never heard of such a service, all of them use their own database. But maybe you could create your own app. [Here](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf) is a good tutorial by Shazam's developpers about how the music recognition works.